# Ломаются цвета в консоли при работе с git

Tags: git, shell

Почему-то при работе с `git` в *nix-like консоли ломаются цвета: весь текст выводится дефолтным цветом, а строки, которые должны быть цветными, оказываются обрамлены кодами цветов:

> **ESC[33m**commit 53f26c1fa4dc4f66df6a0fd01677bb3f7d1da12d**ESC[m**

При этом цветной вывод `ls --color`, например, работает нормально.

Проблема воспроизводится в некоторых дистрибутивах Linux и во FreeBSD. Как быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причина проблемы в том, что вывод `git` отображается посредством системной утилиты `less`, которая по умолчанию не умеет работать с ANSI-последовательностями, обозначающими границы цветного выделения текста в консоли (точнее, посредством того, что находится в переменной окружения `$PAGER`).

Чтобы `less` отображал цветные строки, нужно добавить к его вызову ключ `-R`:

```
   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are
          output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen
          appearance is maintained correctly in most cases.
          ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the
          form:

               ESC [ ... m

          where the "..." is zero or more color specification
          characters
```

Данный флаг можно добавлять непосредственно к вызову `less` или в содержимое переменной окружения `$LESS`. Во втором случае `$PAGER` останется неизменным, но искомый эффект будет достигнут, так как `less` считает из окружения "свою" переменную `$LESS` и добавит к себе флаг `-R` прозрачно.

**Итого, проблему можно решить следующими способами:**

1. Либо передавать нужный флаг через окружение каждый раз непосредственно перед вызовом `git`:

   ```
   $ LESS=-R git log
   ```

   Данный метод - наименее "инвазивный" и ничего не меняет в настройках git и системы.
2. Либо объявив флаг для `less` в общесистемное окружение через глобальный конфиг вашего shell-а: например, в случае `bash`, внеся следующую строчку в `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export LESS=-R
   ```
3. Либо отказаться от использования git-ом общесистемного `$PAGER`, прописав вызов `less` в явном виде в конфиг git-а:

   ```
   $ git config --global core.pager "less -R"
   ```

   Этот метод позволяет не беспокоиться о том, что при изменении системных настроек изменится поведение git.
4. Впрочем, можно и глобально переопределить `$PAGER`, снабдив вызов `less` произвольным набором флагов (см. `man less`): например, в случае `bash`, внеся следующую строчку в `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export PAGER='env LESS_IS_MORE=1 less -FRX'
   ```

   Этот метод затронет вывод не только git, но и многих других "длинных" команд, например того же `man`.